# Error con API de Battlefield 4

Tags: javascript, api

Tengo un error al hacer este código en el que quiero coger todos los datos de cada consola en concreto label y count de la API de [Battlefield4](https://api.bf4stats.com/api/onlinePlayers) y mostrarlo por gráfica y no sé porqué me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 $http.get(api4).then(function(response) {
     let uvCharts = [];

        response.data.forEach(function(elem) { //cojo objetos pc,ps3,xbox etc
            let name = elem.label;
            let value = elem.count;
            if (name && value && !isNaN(value)) // compruebo que hay name y value y que el value es un número
                uvCharts.push({ "name": name, "value": value });
        });

        var graphdef = {
            categories: ['uvCharts'],
            dataset: {
                'uvCharts': uvCharts,
            }
        };


        var chart = uv.chart('Pie', graphdef, {
            meta: {
                caption: 'Stats of connected players in Battlefield 4',
                hlabel: 'Years',
                vlabel: 'Number of users',
                vsublabel: 'in thousands'
            }
        });


    });
```

EDIT1:

También he probado con este código pero ahora en no me lanza ningún error sino que me lanza la gráfica vacía y no se muestra

```
$http.get(api4).then(function(response) {
     var uvCharts = [];
             var i;
            for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                if (response.data[i].label && response.data[i].count && !isNaN(response.data[i].count)) // compruebo que hay name y build time y que el name no es un número

                    uvCharts.push({ "name": response.data[i].label, "value": response.data[i].count });
            }



        var graphdef = {
            categories: ['uvCharts'],
            dataset: {
                'uvCharts': uvCharts,
            }
        };


        var chart = uv.chart('Pie', graphdef, {
            meta: {
                caption: 'Stats of connected players in Battlefield 4',
                hlabel: 'Years',
                vlabel: 'Number of users',
                vsublabel: 'in thousands'
            }
        });


    });
```

EDIT 2: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la llamada a la api4 te esta devolviendo un response, pero el data esta vacio, o contiene un elemento que no es iterable (una cadena por ej) revisa si haciendo un curl a dicha api4 te devuelve algun resultado.

Comment: cuando abro api4 me devuelve los datos en json iguales que en la api de Battlefield

Comment: ok, entonces haz un console.output(response.data) antes del response.data.foreach, y publica lo que te sale, a ver si te esta devolviendo otro objeto en ese punto.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos cuál es la respuesta que te da la API?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con los datos que me arroja el response.data

Comment: y si conviertes `response.data` a JSON usando `JSON.parse(reponse.data)`, con eso podrás manipular el resultado ya que te regresa objetos ejemplo `let data = JSON.parse(response.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de iterar sobre un objeto, los objetos no son iterables utilizando el método `forEach`. En lugar de eso prueba a utilizar `for .. in ..` de la siguiente manera.

```
for(const elem in response.data) {
    let name = response.data[elem].label;
    let value = response.data[elem].count;

    if (name && value && !isNaN(value)) // compruebo que hay name y value y que el value es un número
    uvCharts.push({ name, value });
}
```

Comment: Ahora no arroja el error pero no aparece siquiera la gráfica

Comment: Acabo de editar el snippet, tenía un typo, pruébalo ahora